# Rake task to fetch XML stream with nogokiri and write selected fields to DB

Tags: xml, rake, nokogiri, database

I am trying to build a rake tasks, that fetches a product feed and adds it to my db.

```
task :testme => :environment do
require 'nokogiri'
require 'zlib'
require 'open-uri'


  @url = "http://some_url/filename.xml.gz"
  @source = open((@url), :http_basic_authentication=>[USERID, "PASSWORD"])
  @gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(@source)
  @result = @gz.read
  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(@result)

  @doc.xpath("//product").each do |item|
    Product.create(:productname => product.css("name").text)
  end

end
```

So this works fine until

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(@result)
```

which throws a rake error

```
File name too long (repeating the content of xml- document)
```

That's really confusing, because I developed and tested it in a model, where I could read, unzip and search the file and then write the desired fields with put.

Do you have an idea?

Cheers,

Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

was missing.